# Javascript RegExp matching returning too many

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need to take a string and get some values from it. I have this string:

```
'tab/tab2/tab3'
```

The '/tab3' is optional so this string should also work:

```
'tab/tab2'
```

I currently am trying this which works for the most part:

```
'tab/tab2/tab3'.match(new RegExp('^tab/([%a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s,]+)(/([%a-zA-Z0-9-_s,]+)?)$'));
```

This will return:

```
["tab/tab2/tab3", "tab2", "/tab3", "tab3"]
```

but I want it to return

```
["tab/tab2/tab3", "tab2", "tab3"]
```

So I need to get rid of the 3rd index item ("/tab3") and also get it to work with just the 'tab/tab2' string.

To complicate it even more, I only have control over the `/([%a-zA-Z0-9-_s,]+)?` part in the last grouping meaning it will always wrap in a grouping.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need regex for this, just use `split()` method:

```
var str = 'tab/tab2/tab3';
var arr = str.split('/');

console.log(arr[0]); //tab
console.log(arr[1]); //tab2
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/9Mwqz/)

Comment: For this simple example yes but there is much more going on that needs RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

I used this regexp to do this:

```
'tab/tab2/tab3'.match(new RegExp('^tab/([%a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s,]+)(?:/)([%a-zA-Z0-9-_s,]+)$'));
```

Now I get this return

```
["tab/tab2/tab3", "tab2", "tab3"]
```

Now I just need to allow 'tab/tab2' to be accepted aswell...

Comment: Used this:

    'tab/tab2'.match(new RegExp('^tab/([%a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s,]+)(?:(?:/){1}([%a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s,]+))?$'))

Answer (score 0):

Do not put regex between " or ', using /g to make global search else only first occurrence is returned

```
"tab/tab2/tab3".match(/tab[0-9]/g)
```

Comment: This is true, internal code actually uses new RegExp to use a string that is generated (reason why I only have access to last grouping). Have updated original post to reflect this: